# C# - Print a PDF Error (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:...)

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I am trying to write an application to print PDFs.
Now I get an error message where I can't get any further after a long search.

The goal would be to print a PDF file without opening the PDF-Reader.

My Code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.Verb = "print";
            info.FileName = @"C:\testFile.pdf";
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();

            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                p.Kill();
        }
```

The error condition occurs at **p.Start();** line.

Error message:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "The system cannot find the
> specified file".

**New experience: 20.01.2021**

If I comment out `info.Verb = "print";`. Then the PDF is opened.
Is this a sign that it finds the PDF but has no access to printer?

Comment: Do you a file called testFile.pdf at c:?

Comment: Try using a less restricted location than the system root.

Comment: @Mangs yes the path are correct

Comment: @Alex K. i will try.. But what does that have to do with it? I don't want to save anything, I just want to print it. I'm sorry if I don't understand correctly. I am still beginner.

Comment: Not really sure how this would work, but the error message tells you that it can't find the file or dosen't have access to it. Therefore a different path could help you.

Comment: If I comment out (info.Verb = "print";). Then the PDF is opened.

Is this a sign that it finds the PDF but has no access to printer?

Answer (score 0):

use this code it works for me :

```cs
    public static void PrintToASpecificPirnter()
    {
        using (PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog())
        {
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                StartInfo.Verb = "printTo";
                StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\"";
                StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                StartInfo.FileName = fileName;

                Process.Start(StartInfo);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: fileName is the name of the file and the path.